# How do I get the Url and pass down the variable at the same time for React route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
let iwantToPassThisVariable='iwantToPassThisVariable'

        <Route path='/AAA/:ID' component={BBB} iwantToPassThisVariable={iwantToPassThisVariable} />
```

but I am not able to pass down this variable for this  format

so I change it to

```
   <Route path='/AAA/:ID' exact  >
            <BBB  iwantToPassThisVariable={iwantToPassThisVariable} />
          </Route>
```

I can pass down the variable at this kind of format, but I am not able to use

```
 const { ID } = match.params;
```

How can I pass down the variable and use

const { ID } = match.params;

at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement like this:

```js
<Route path='/AAA/:ID' render={() => <BBB  iwantToPassThisVariable={iwantToPassThisVariable} />} />
```